# Redirects HTTP requests avoiding controller action issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, controller

I am using Ruby on Rails 3. In my project I have many classes and some of those are stated in the `routes.rb` file like the following:

```
#routers.rb
resources :users

namespace "users" do
  resources :profiles
  ...
end
```

With the above code I can access the following URLs:

```
<my_web_site>/users/1
<my_web_site>/users/1/edit
...
# and also
<my_web_site>/users/profiles/1
<my_web_site>/users/profiles/1/edit
...
```

What I would like to do is **to redirect some URL requests to others URL** but if in the `routes.rb` file I redirect all those, some controller actions will not work properly because also those requests are redirected (GET, POST, ...).

**How can I solve this issue?**

P.S.: I know that (maybe) my router statements are wrong, but at the moment I am looking for a easy solution too the problem. However suggestions about this matter are welcome.

Comment: Can you please add some more detailed examples of the redirections that you need and the redirections that are not working properly ?

Comment: @NeX At this time all URL work property because I didn't change nothing, yet... I will update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, looks like you want to set up a redirection that will only apply for to a given path and just one HTTP verb. This seems to be what you are looking for:

```
#routers.rb
resources :users

match "/users/profile/:id" => redirect("/profiles/%{id}"), :via => :get

namespace "users" do
  resources :profiles
  ...
end
```

Based on this routes every `GET`request hitting `/users/profile/1` will be redirected to `/profiles/1` while any `POST`, `PUT` or `DELETE` requests won't be suffering the redirection.

The `:via` param will execure the redirection only if the request method math the given value. It also accepts an array of verbs so, for example,  you can redirect `:via => [:post, :put]`

If you add more detailed information about the specific redirections that you need we can create a better example.

Answer (score 0):

Check this great article, it will help you: 
[routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

you can define urls that you need to redirect to in `routes.rb`.
For example:
`match 'some_url/:id' => redirect_to('/path_to_redirect')`